# Remove a BlurEffect from control WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a border containing a textblock, which has a blur effect applied to it:

```
<Border Grid.Row="2">
    <Border.Effect>
        <BlurEffect Radius="5" />
    </Border.Effect>
    <TextBlock/>
</Border>
```

I want to remove this BlurEffect on a button press, but I cannot find how.
I have tried to set the radius to 0, but the text is still blurred.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you could use triggers. If you and set the style. If you want Mousedown you should look for EventTrigger. Basically something like this ... just adjusted to your use case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749882/how-can-i-set-a-property-of-a-dropshadoweffect-via-a-trigger-in-a-controltemplat?msclkid=0f461812cd3d11ec8ab18705d247dfa1

Answer (score 1):

One option is to set the radius by a Setter in a Trigger or DataTrigger. This however is a bit complicated since you can't add a Stye inside the Effect. (See also the link provided by @silverfighter in the comments.)

One easy solution is to bind the `Radius` to a property and change it from code like so:

```
<Border>
   <Border.Effect>
       <BlurEffect Radius="{Binding MyBlurRadius}" />
   </Border.Effect>
</Border>
```

Your ViewModel then needs to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and provide a property `MyBlurRadius` which calls `OnPropertyChanged()` in its setter:

```
public MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _myBlurRadius;

    public int MyBlurRadius
    {
        get { return _myBlurRadius; }
        set
        {
            if (_myBlurRadius == value)
                return;
            _myBlurRadius = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

As log as there is no other setter rechanging the radius, the blur will disapear once the radius is set to 0.

The drawback of this soultion is that you have to deal with visualisation from inside your code.

Comment: Thank you. I haven’t tried it yet and I will be sure to, but I was able to get the radius back to zero inside an event handler, but the text was still rendered in some funny way - it definitely wasn’t as clear as before. Is this different, if so why?

Comment: Hum, i can find no difference in my example view between a blurr effect with radius 0 and no blurr efect at all. There is most likely some other reason which interferes with the blurr effect like the rendering of pixels depending on user control size which is discussed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31028924/15432738).

Comment: It would be nice to use "UIElement":
<UIElement.Effect>
    <BlurEffect Radius="{Binding BlurRadiusValue}" KernelType="Gaussian"/>
</UIElement.Effect>